# how to cycle through list indefinitely and lazily in Raku?

Tags: list, lazy-evaluation, raku, lazy-sequences, rakudo

This is mostly to geek out on how awesome [Raku](https://docs.raku.org/) is.

**Question**

Are there built-in methods that will take a list and cycle through it indefinitely, producing, say, the lazy list

```
a, b, c, a, b, c, ...
```

out of `(a, b, c)`? Nothing in the [documentation](https://docs.raku.org/type/List) on lists seems to obviously do the trick.

**Possible solutions**

I can think of at least a couple.

The more plodding down-to-earth method would be to [map](https://docs.raku.org/type/Map) `@array[<variable> mod length-of-@array]` over the lazy range `0..Inf`. In the `perl6` REPL:

```
> my @ar=<a b c>
[a b c]
> (0..Inf).map({ @ar[$_ % @ar.elems] }).[0..100]
(a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a ...)
```

A cooler (I think) solution would have you first turn your list into a [slip](https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#prefix_%7C), and then apply the [repetition operator](https://docs.raku.org/routine/xx) to that slip indefinitely:

```
> my @ar=<a b c>
[a b c]
> (|@ar xx *).[0..100]
(a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a ...)
```

**Conclusion**

Even though I can achieve this (and the last solution in particular is very pithy and satisfying), what I am wondering is whether I'm missing anything built in specifically for this purpose.

---

**Edit Re: the accepted answer**

This is to elaborate slightly on the answer by @Brad Gilbert. The `«~»` operator wraps [string concatenation](https://docs.raku.org/language/5to6-perlop#Additive_operators) `~` in the `« »` [hyper operator](https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#Hyper_operators), which results in applying the wrapped binary operator to elements selected sequentially from the two lists.

So to achieve what I wanted (list-cycling to a desired length, like say 100), one would do

```
<a b c> <<~>> ("" xx 100)
```

This produces

```
(a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a b c a)
```

(100 entries). It does have a couple of drawbacks though:

- it coerces the list entries to strings, due to the application of `~`
- it doesn't actually produce a lazy infinite list:

```
<a b c> <<~>> ("" xx *)
```

returns

```
List on right side of hyperop of infix:<~> is known to be infinite
  in block <unit> at <unknown file> line 1
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When it can be written this short, why add a feature just for that. Especially since it is probably a rare event that you would need such a thing.

```raku
|< a b c > xx *
```

Well there is one exception, if you use something like `«~»` it extend it out for you.

```raku
< a b c > «~» (1..10)
# (a1 b2 c3 a4 b5 c6 a7 b8 c9 a10)
```

Comment: Thanks! I agree with the sentiment (that a specific operator shouldn't be necessary), but I'm glad I asked: you provided a solution relying on the list-specific docs that I'd missed. I've accepted the answer and will edit my question to include some references.

Comment: I realized this does not produce an infinite lazy list though: see the edit. That's all right, as I only expect to use this for selecting a specific number of entries.

Comment: `(|< a b c > xx *)[0..99].put` works as does `(|@ar xx *)[0..99].put`

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if I understood the problem. But what I understood that you need a method to produce infinite list following a pattern. Well if that's the problem
in the book "[Think in Raku](https://greenteapress.com/wp/think-perl-6/)" comes with something that may help, in the part 14.5  (adapted from how to do a Fibonacci sequence)

```
("a","b","c", -> $a, $b, $c {$a} ...* )
```

this element is the pure-list, if you want the extract values you need something like more conventional on list (like assign & extract values)

```
my @list = ("a","b","c", -> $a, $b, $c {$a} ...* )
@list[0..100]
@list[91]
```

I think that's it's not good idea using map in a *Inf* context, but please tell me if I missed something, i still learning about this awesome language too !!

Comment: thank you very much, but I wanted this to work for arbitrary lists in place of your `"a","b","c"`. So I'd propose `my @inf_list=(|@orig_list, sub (*@ar) { @ar[*-@orig_list] } ...*)`

Comment: Ohhh I understand now, well your method has the advantage of encapsulate as a method to use with any list. Well re-implement my answers I think is more clear flatten the list and repeat itself flattened `my @list = <a 2 v c>; my @inf_list = (|@list, -> {|@list} ...* )`

Comment: Fair enough, but then you don't need the arrow `->` :)

Answer (score 1):

Your first "down-to-earth" example can be written as `(^Inf).map({ @ar[$_ % *] })`

Also, the slip and repetition works fine, but only for reasonably sized lists.

```
sub bad-cycle(@xs) {
    |@xs xx Inf
}

my $big-list = ^1e6;
say bad-cycle($big-list).head(100);    # Hangs for several seconds
```

A better option would be a map like shown above, or a `gather` loop like so

```
sub cycle(@xs) {
    gather loop { .take for @xs }
}

say cycle($big-list).head(100);    # Instant output
```